# Root cause analysis library for ROS?

Tags: ros, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

A lot of times when we develop ROS systems with multiple different nodes communicating w each other, it goes without saying that there are going to be a few bugs introduced. And it gets hard to track the root cause for that bug.

It may appear that the bug is in node A but suppose node A depends on something in node B and that in turn on node C, the root cause of the problem could be in node C. Are there any ROS libraries that look at root cause analysis in complex ROS systems? Or any libraries or general sources of information I could check out for this kind of thing.

I am not sure what this would be classified as so I couldn't get the right Google keywords to make a good search.

If not, I would be interested in writing something like that. Is there a forum to discuss such kind of stuff and see if there would be someone else also interested in the same?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265953/root-cause-analysis-library-for-ros?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-11**:
I'd second @ahendrix's comment. There are probably approaches from academia, but I've not seen those applied to ROS applications, or made available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a fairly substantial software engineering problem, and I'm not sure you're going to find a library that just solves it, or even how that library might work, but I'm curious to see what you find!

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0